# Meanings of participles

Tags: past-participles, participles

From the book *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*:

> "That's mine!" said Harry, trying to snatch it back.
>    
>  "Who'd be writing to you?" sneered Uncle Vernon, (1) **shaking** the letter open with one hand and (2) **glancing** at it...
> "Let me see it!"
>    demanded Dudley. 
>  "OUT!" roared Uncle Vernon, and he took both Harry
>    and Dudley by the scruffs of their necks and threw them into the hall,
>    (3) **slamming** the kitchen door behind them.

Participial phrases (1) and (2) seem to happen at the same time as the main clause. But (3) seems to happen after the main clause. Is it right?

Comment: In my mind's eye, it all happened in the order I read it in.

Comment: Yes, I can see better. So, it's like a sequential events, all three of the participial phrases. Rather than simultaneous, right?

Comment: The participles are simultaneous with Reference Time, which in narrative constantly moves forward: *sneered*, *demanded*, *roared*, *took*, *threw*. Think of them as 'stage directions' in a script.

Comment: @StoneyB, Your name wih ‘stage directions’ finally put on my Harry Potter book, and I recollect when I started to learn English. At first I started with dramas with Oscar, Beckett, Bernard Shaw, and I forgot his name.. over a woman who had to go to a mental asylum by his sister and brother-in-law, with resignation and preter-secular odd chuckles.. And they were not easy, so I moved into the Neil Simon’s ‘The Collected Plays of Neil Simon. Vol 2’.

Comment: @StoneyB, If anyone asks why do you learn English, I would say to get into the human dramas. I’ve found BBC runs a drama-specialized radio channel, Radio Extra. That’s why I named myself “Listenever.” I want to laugh and mourn with the dramas. That’s why I started to read English novels. Yeah, someday, I would like to listen to the BBC’s radio dramas and read the English novels in depth. There I find common human nature, though different in the vibes with my mother tongue, other than my pleasure.

Comment: I think the one you forget is Tennessee Williams' *A Streetcar Named Desire*. ... Tense, at least, is a lot easier to sort out in drama!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncle Vernon obviously can't glance at the letter until *after* he's shaken it open, and he can't slam the kitchen door until *after* he's thrown Harry and Dudley through it into the hall. It's just like...

> [[The sherrif] drew his gun **and** shot [the outlaw]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22drew%20his%20gun%20and%20shot%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...where ***and*** can be understood as meaning *[and] **then***. In most cases, only context and logic tells you whether ***and*** implies *at the same time* or *[immediately] afterwards* (or if it even makes any difference).

As regards whether Uncle Vernon actually said the words *"Who'd be writing to you?"* before or while shaking the letter out [and reading it], I think that falls into the "makes no difference" category.